# To place before after css selector on a popup modal wrt to the hovered element position

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors

I am trying to position the ::before ::after css selector to the popup modal whenever the box is hovered

Reproducible stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o389e8?file=src/app/app.component.scss

The css selector should be placed before or after the popup modal and positioned vertical center w.r.t the hovered box.
So the arrow should appear attached to the popup modal, similar we have for a tooltip

The positioning of modal per say is already as per expectation , only the ::before ::after arrow positioning needs to be corrected.

Only For reference

[image]

Comment: so, the array needs to be sticking to the modal right?

Comment: Yes correct but wrt the hovered box, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `:before`, you can create the arrow using `clip-path`

```css
.arrow {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Now, you can use [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) to get hold of the `fs-modal` element and change the top value for `.arrow` class

[Updated StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytnzmy)

Comment: the `remove()` isnt an option as it will remove the element. You are in the correct direction with having a class to hide the arrow when clicked..

Comment: can you raise that as a different post, please? or else this answer becomes too broad wrt the question.